# SQLAlchemy: Add Self-referential Hierarchical Object -- Causing sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError

Tags: json, python-3.x, orm, sqlalchemy

Fairly new to Python & SQLAlchemy from C#/EF world; attempting to do something which is pretty simple in the latter, so I assume it must at least be possible in the former.

Problem: loading table from JSON data, but table is defined by an object which has a self-referential hierarchy, like so:

```
class TableMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, jsonData = None):
        if(jsonData is not None):
            self.__dict__ = json.loads(jsonData)

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(self):
        return self.__name__

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)

class HierarchyMixin(object):
    @declared_attr
    def predecessor_id(self):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey(self.__name__ + '.id'))

    @declared_attr
    def successors(self):
        return relationship(self.__name__)

class Something(TableMixin, HierarchyMixin, Base):
    a_property = Column(String)
    b_property = Column(String)
```

And then I have some JSON data, like:

```
{
  "a_property":"some value",
  "b_property":"some other value",
  "successors":[
    {
      "a_property":"some value 1",
      "b_property":"some other value 1"
    },
    {
      "a_property":"some value 2",
      "b_property":"some other value 2"
      "successors":[
      {
        "a_property":"some value 3",
        "b_property":"some other value 3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And my goal is to load that to my database. For that I have:

```
import json
from MyEntities import Something
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker

db_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///my.db', echo=True)
db_conn = db_engine.connect()
Session = sessionmaker(bind = db_engine)
db_sesn = Session()

with open('MyJsonData.json', encoding='utf-8-sig') as json_data_file:
    data = Something(json_data_file.read())

db_sesn.add(data)
db_sesn.commit()
```

It does not work. I get:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'Entities.Something' is mapped, but this instance lacks instrumentation.  This occurs when the instance is created before sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(Entities.Something) was called.
```

I've poked around and found that everything seems to be okay, in the sense that all the data will load and create and object hierarchy. I can confirm by accessing various members of that "data" object, once created. The error arises at the time I attempt the add to the database.

From everything I can tell, this ought not be something simply outside the scope of what I can do with SQLAlchemy. But for the life of me I cannot find a specific example to cover the case I have.

I'll ask to be excused for the time-being for what might be a few "unpythonic" modes of doing things -- I'm still learning :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python + SqlAlchemy: Add Parent/Child Records When Both Parent & Child are New](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59109259/python-sqlalchemy-add-parent-child-records-when-both-parent-child-are-new)

Comment: You can't simply assign to `__dict__` - this will obliterate any instance attributes that have already been assigned.

Comment: @snakecharmerb: Thanks, yes -- I'd very recently gotten that far, and just as of last night have a simple solution that does work. As I'd initially suspected, there isn't anything complicated about it. Will post answer shortly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's only my newness to Python and SqlAlchemy which prevented me from seeing the solution to this right away, which is actually pretty simple.

Sticking with my initial code example, I did:

```
class HierarchyMixin(object):    
    def __init__(self, data = None):
        if data is not None:
            if 'successors' in data:
                self.successors = list(map(self.__class__, data['successors']))
            if 'a_property' in data:
                self.a_property = data['a_property']
            if 'b_property' in data:
                self.b_property = data['b_property']

    @declared_attr
    def predecessor_id(self):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey(self.__name__ + '.id'))

    @declared_attr
    def successors(self):
        return relationship(self.__name__)

    a_property = Column(String)
    b_property = Column(String)

class Something(TableMixin, HierarchyMixin, Base):
    pass
```

All I really am doing, there, is assigning a list to the `successors` property, and that list maps each member to a new instance of the class. And... well, that's pretty-much it.

And then, with the Json data file, I just:

```
with open('MyJsonData.json', encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as json_data:
    not_nothing = Something(json.loads(json_data.read()))
```

And that's all there is to it. The hierarchical data structure imports as relational, with all the predecessor_id keys properly set.

I'm just kinda annoyed with myself for not seeing such an obviously simple thing right off the bat, but I guess chalk it up to learning a new language and not quite *getting* Python. That's changing fast :-)

Comment: man, i works as python dev two years, but it is not simple and not obvious solution for me