# SQLAlchemy relationship to self table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an employees model, one of its fields is the employee's manager, which is an id of another employee (or the same if the employee manages himself).

I tried the following:

```
class Employees(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "employees"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column("first_name", String(20))
    manager = Column("manager", Integer, ForeignKey("employees.id"))
    manager_lnk = relation("Employees", primaryjoin="Employees.manager == Employees.id", back_populates="employees", cascade_backrefs=False)
```

It's not working. When I remove the "back_populates="employees" it seems to accept it, but at runtime a join is missing a parameter.

What is the right way to do this so that I have access to the employee's manager's first name?

Thanks!

Comment: There is an example of a self-referential ORM class in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59121078/2144390).

Comment: Thanks Gord. Helped me!